# Extremely large number of dask tasks for simple computation

Tags: python, numpy, memory, dask

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as dda

def index_nearest(to_find, coord_grid):
    """Return indexes of elements in coord_grid that most 
    closely match the ones in to_find.
    """
    to_find = to_find.reshape(-1,1)
    return np.argmin(np.abs(to_find - coord_grid), axis=1)

n_points = 10000
n_grid = 800

x = np.random.uniform(0, n_grid, [n_points,])
x_grid = np.arange(n_grid)

x_da = dda.from_array(x, chunks=10)
x_grid_da = dda.from_array(x_grid, chunks=10)

index_nearest(x_da, x_grid_da)
```

When running the last line I get a warning that says the number of chunks has been increased by a factor of 40, and the repr looks like this:

[image]

Isn't 270,000 tasks a bit too much for such a simple computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of tasks depends on the number of chunks, especially for operations that require pairwise combinations of different chunks.

Since a chunk with 10 elements takes up 80 bytes, there is usually plenty of room for using bigger chunks, e.g. increasing chunk size to 1_000 elements increases memory load of a single chunk to about 8 kilobytes, while the number of tasks to simply create `x_da` goes down from 1000 to 10. Using chunk size of 1_000 decreases task count for the complete operation to 61 tasks.

Chunk size of 1_000 is still rather small, in many cases one could probably get away with chunk sizes on the scale of 100 MB or even more (depends on the hardware and the types of computations performed).

Comment: ah! I've confused `chunks=how many chunks do you want` with `chunks=how big do you want your chunks to be`

Comment: I see that for example size 1_000 works fine but going to 10_000 causes the computation to never start (even though chunk size is still quite small). I'm guessing this is because `to_find - coord_grid` creates an array with shape `(n_points, n_grid)` which is potentially way too large.

Comment: Yes, that's true, for these types of computations intermediate memory requirements will expand very fast with the chunk size...

Comment: I guess the only way to go around this is ad-hoc resizing before and after the heavy computation?

Comment: Resizing also has its costs (additional tasks plus data shuffling), so in many cases one will want to plan for all of these things in advance (memory requirements given chunk size, and chunk sizes/reshapes)...

Comment: @duff18 You may also find this blog post on [Choosing good chunk sizes in Dask](https://blog.dask.org/2021/11/02/choosing-dask-chunk-sizes) interesting. :)

Comment: coming back to this after a while but...  when the chunks are too small, why does dask warns with `Increasing number of chunks by factor of ...`? the message seems to imply that there will be even more, and hence smaller, chunks...

Comment: Yes, dask is sending a warning that the operation being performed increases fragmentation (number of chunks), so workload on the scheduler and workers will increase substantially.

Comment: wait, I don't get it. I have very small chunks, which means a large number of chunks, and dask is telling that it's making even more chunks?